# Fetch request in Swift 2.1.1

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to convert my Swift 1 code into Swift 2.1.1 code.
So I am trying to add a fetchRequest.

In Swift 1 I did this:

```
if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error), 
   let managedObject = results.first as? NSManagedObject {
       context.deleteObject(managedObject)
    }

let saveError: NSError?
context.save(nil)
```

and

```
 var error: NSError?
 let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]?
 if let results = fetchedResults {
      people = results
   } 
   else {
      print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
   }
```

Swift 2.1 (2nd request -> doesn't work):

```
do {
  let fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
   // success if it gets here
   if let results = fetchedResults {
        people = results
    }
 } catch let error as NSError {
    // failed so print error
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
 }
```

Errors in line (`if let results... & let fetchedResults...`):

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AnyObject]'
```

`Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`

Errors in line (`let fetchedResults...`):

`Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`

`Cannot downcast from '[AnyObject]' to a more optional type '[NSManagedObject]?'`

Could you please help me to translate this into Swift 2.1.1? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: When asking for help it would be helpful to show where you are having trouble. What error messages is this code sample giving you and what do you think those mean? What have you already tried? Otherwise it's hard to know what would help you and this can read like a request to do work for you.

Comment: I updated my question with some more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `do` `catch` block. It will print an error if the `let results` line fails.

```
do {
    let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    // success if it gets here
    if let managedObject = results.first as? NSManagedObject {
        context.deleteObject(managedObject)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    // failed so print error
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

**EDIT**

Second request:

```
do {
  let fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
   // success if it gets here
   if let results = fetchedResults as? [NSManagedObject]{
        people = results
    }
 } catch let error as NSError {
    // failed so print error
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
 }
```

Comment: I added my try in the question but need your help once more please.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help!